# Problem installing Usearch in Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run usearch v11.0,667 (-32bit) through the Ubuntu Bash in Windows 10 (-64bit). I downloaded it and made it executable via chmod:

```
~/user_bin# ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3024491 Nov 20 17:50 usearch
```

And my folder (user_bin) is already in the PATH (I have other programs there and run without problem). However, when I try to use usearch (for example trying the command help) I get this message:

```
-bash:/root/user_bin/usearch: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I know that the usearch version is for -32bit and my system is -64bit based, but other colleagues with -64bit systems can run it.

I tried with usearch for linux and for Windows but I always have the same result, the file seems to be executable but there is an error in it.

Any idea of why I have this error and how to solve it?

If I run file `/root/user_bin/usearch` I obtain this:

`/root/user_bin/usearch: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=71eedf15f5d1c91b7273cb867c2b52533b172610, stripped`

Comment: What does `file /root/user_bin/usearch` return? [Edit] the question and tell us.

Comment: Though, this is probably better suited for https://superuser.com/ or something, as it doesn't really have anything to do with coding. This is probably a duplicate: https://superuser.com/q/1122188/609232

Comment: If you want 32bit support see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2468). If the executable is for Windows use `Usearch.exe` command (see the `.exe` extension).

Comment: @jdv I already edit the question to show what does the file contains :)

Comment: Yeah, you are going to have to pay for the software to get 64-bit Linux support, wait for Microsoft to support 32-bit Linux apps in WSL, or run the Windows executable. See https://superuser.com/q/961171/609232 (But, not really on-topic for SO, like I said earlier.)

Comment: Ok thank you @jdv I was avoiding to install virtual box, but I think is indeed a good alternative, thanks for the links, I'll try with the suggestions there...

Comment: Surely you can run a 32-bit Windows app on Windows 10? That is, not through WSL, but at a regular cmd.exe shell.